# Are you allowed to put up flyers for non-comercial purposes in Brsibane Queensland?

Tags: australia

I'm planning on putting up A4 posters about community activism. I'm wondering if/where it is legal in Brisbane Australia?

Answer (score 0):

### Do you have permission of the person who owns the thing you want to put them on?

Attaching a flyer to someone else's wall, car, pole etc. without permission is trespass.

### How are you collecting them afterwards?

There are laws against littering in Queensland.